# Webpack error on lodash load using externals config

Tags: javascript, webpack, lodash, webpack-externals

i am trying to modify a current project using webpack. On my scripts i am using lodash library but i have also scripts that are not written on ES6 so i load lodash globally using a normal script tag.
Based on the webpack documentation i have added the below config on the webpack (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/).

```
lodash : {
        commonjs: 'lodash',
        amd: 'lodash',
        root: '_' // indicates global variable
      },
```

I compile the code using babel without any problem but when the actual code is executed i receive the below error
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"

If i remove the `import _ from "lodash";` statement from the file then the issue is resolved and script is working as expected as _ is on global.

But this was expected to work also without adding the externals correct ? According with the webpack example for jquery

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery'
  }
};
```

The below code will be unchanged

```
import $ from 'jquery';
$('.my-element').animate(/* ... */);
```

In my case why is not working ? Any suggestions ? ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I think i found a solution, after i read the documentation again and again i noticed that message which is also on yellow border

```
An object with { root, amd, commonjs, ... } is only allowed for libraryTarget: 'umd'. It's not allowed for other library targets.
```

So i have changed my config from

```
lodash : {
      commonjs: 'lodash',
      amd: 'lodash',
      root: '_' // indicates global variable
    }
```

to

```
lodash: '_'
```

and issue solved, now is working as expected. It will be great of course if i understand why this was an issue

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, and changed the externalsType: 'window'

```
{
   externalsType: 'window',
   externals: {
     lodash: '_'
   },
   ...

}
```

almost solve the problem, but, In the following condition, throw errors:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
const { get } = _;
```